# c# equivalent forVFP FileToStr()

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I'm migrating to c# from VFP and need help with `FileToStr(path)`, actually we have thousands of files stored into a database with this function, and for now we want to maintain compatibility with VFP.

FileToStr() help at VFP help library doesn't say anything about what kind of Encoding perform with the file just

```
FILETOSTR(cFileName) = Returns the contents of a file as a character string.
```

For now this is a Black Box. I have two questions:

There is a c# function that perform the same task as VFP `FileToStr()`?

What Kind of encoding perform `FileToStr()` to the file?

Actually I have this function to convert the file:

```
public async Task<string> ImageToStrAsync(string path)
{
    string BitmapToImage = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
             Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(path);
             TypeConverter cv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
             return Convert.ToBase64String(
                     (byte[])cv.ConvertTo(bm, typeof(byte[]))
                 );
         });

    return BitmapToImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another had previously answered and then deleted it... Don't know why.

What you are looking for is...

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( someFileNameVariable );
```

OR

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( someFileNameVariable, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 );
```

(or other encoding option... ASCII, UTF7, etc as enumerated option).

As for binary, such as for image files..

```
byte[] binaryContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes( someBinaryFileName );
```

And to get a byte[] array that you have stored, such as a bitmap image into an actual image object, you could do the following.

```
BitmapImage yourBmp = new BitmapImage();
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(binaryContent))
{
    yourBmp.BeginInit();
    yourBmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    yourBmp.StreamSource = ms;
    yourBmp.EndInit();
}
```

And converting a byte array to a string...

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for help.. ``System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes`` is equivalent for ``STRCONV(ImageFile)`` , if yes could you please explain me how to sabe Byte[] to string ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez, revised answer for converting byte[] to image or string too.